# React component with react-router inside an app with react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am developing a react component with its own react-router-dom to be able to handle paths like `/post` and `/post/123`.

I need to package this component as npm module so it can be embedded inside another React app with its own react-router-dom.

Hosting app:

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/posts" exact={true}>
      <Blog />
    </Route>
  </Switch>
</Router
```

and in the Blog component:

```
<Router basename="/posts">
   <Switch>
     <Route path="/">
       <p>Display all posts</p>
     </Route>
     <Route path="/post/:id">
       <p>Display details for post with id</p>
     </Route>
   </Switch>
</Router>
```

When I visit the `/posts` path I get the `Display all posts` message. However when I visit `/post/123` path I don't see the `Display details for post with id` message.

How can I get the inner router paths work with the outside router?

Comment: The `Route` in the Hosting app can't have the `exact` prop set to true if you want non-exact routes to match in it's children.

Comment: When I remove the `exact` prop in the hosting app and visit the `/posts/post/:id` route I get the `Display all posts` text. Seems like the issues is that the inner Router can't detect the url change

Answer (score 0):

you are missing keyword exact

```
 <Router basename="/posts">
       <Switch>
         <Route exact path="/">
           <p>Display all posts</p>
         </Route>
         <Route exact path="/post/:id">
           <p>Display details for post with id</p>
         </Route>
       </Switch>
    </Router>
```

Comment: Nope - adding `exact` does not change anything. Clicking on a post to see the post details does change the url in the browser but it does not render the details. Refreshing the browser then renders the main app's 404 page

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling across this issue - I solved it by passing in `history` to both routers:

The main app:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/posts">
          <Blog />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

The Blog component:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const Blog = () => {
  return (
    <Router basename="/posts">
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact>
          <p>Display all posts</p>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/post/:id" exact>
          <p>Display details for post with id</p>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

Comment: `useHistory` will only work to provide `history` to the sub-router if there is a parent `Router` to create that history. If there *has* to be a parent router in order for this to work, my question is - why have the sub-router at all? What does it provide besides the `basename` prefixed to all the routes? I would just use a nested `Switch` and remove the `Router` entirely from the `Blog`.

Comment: The issue is that the Blog component is an external component added to App as an npm package. Since the Blog component contains links (in the Posts component to link to the post details page) it has to contain `Router` - otherwise I get an 'invariant violation' error. You are correct thought - the parent `Router` needs the `history` prop and not the child - I updated my answer accordingly

Comment: And that doesn't throw an error in the parent?

Comment: @BrianThompson you are correct - updated my answer accordingly. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is Complete Solution: Try to do This:

> If You are using basename in "Router" Do like this

```
const BlogPage = () =>{
    return(
        <Router basename='/posts'>
            <Switch>
                <Route path='/posts' exact>
                    <p>Display All Posts </p>
                </Route>
                <Route path='/:id' exact>
                    <p>Display Post with Id </p>
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    )
}
```

> Or If you are doing Router without using basename then it should something like this:

```
const BlogPage = () =>{
    return(
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route path='/posts' exact>
                    <p>Display All Posts </p>
                </Route>
                <Route path='/posts/:id/' exact>
                    <p>Display Post with Id </p>
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    )
}
```

> See the  Difference between both of them

Comment: This isn't the same as what they have. They have a basename of "posts" and then the sub-router has "post" - singular.  The first example would also yeild "posts/posts" which also isn't what they have.